# Installing AER but it does not recognizing the package "car"

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install the AER but it has presented error of not recognizing the package "car". I have already installed and uninstalled and installed the "car" package, and also AER several times and the error persists. Anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to provide a bit more information: the software version(s) involved, how you are doing the install, and the exact error message you are getting. This will make it easier for the community to help you. Thanks.

Comment: The version i am using is Version 1.1.456 – © 2009-2018 RStudio, Inc. and the error is...> library(AER)
Carregando pacotes exigidos: car
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘haven’ 1.0.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘AER’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
2: package ‘car’ was built under R version 3.5.1 
Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded

Comment: Thanks. Please put this information in the actual question though, via the edit button.

Comment: When editing your question, please include your R version (first line of `sessionInfo()`); your RStudio version happens to be irrelevant to this question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is the package not updated to align with its dependencies.

The latest `AER` package version is `1.2-5`, and `haven` package version is 1.1.2.

Try to update your packages to latest.